# How to select all classes inside a class with jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, css

How do I go about selecting all classes in a class using a jquery selector? You would think something like `$(".content .*").click();` would work.

In addition, on click of any class in .content I want to store the class name of the clicked class in a variable.

Comment: Store which class name? Agreed with @zerkms; the second question makes no sense.

Comment: The class which was clicked.

Comment: Classes are not clicked. Elements are. As always, you can access the clicked element with `this` in the callback.

Comment: Ah. So I want to store the class name of any element that contains a class in a variable. But this would need a property right? Something like this.value or this.class?

Comment: [`this.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a selector for all elements that have at least one class specified

```
$('.content [class]')
```

or here is just all elements

```
$('.content *')
```

or the better:

```
$('.content').on('click', '*', function() { //handler here });
```

Your second question doesn't make much sense and needs to be rephrased

Comment: How would I extend on "$('.content [class]')" so that in selects any class within a class in .content?

Comment: @sephiith: what is "any class"?

Comment: By any class I mean the class inside the class inside .content

Comment: @sephiith: what is "the class inside the class inside .content"? There are only DOM nodes in the DOM tree

Comment: <div class="content"> <div class="random"> <div class="link1"</div></div></div> The selector should only select <div class="link1"</div> (With the link1 and random class being anything. *)

Comment: @sephiith: I'm missing your point. What is the formal criteria to select `div class="link1"` and to skip `div class="random"`?

Comment: The answer to my question was: $('.content [class] [class]')

Comment: @sephiith: it's really weird :-) I'm sure if you explained your **original task** we could provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select child elements of ".content" with any class, try this:

`$(".content [class]").click`

Answer (score 0):

```
   var $allClassElements =  $('[class]', '.content')
```

should do

Then for further reference of these elements just use the cached variable

```
 $allClassElements.something
```